# main differences between PC and a Power PC

Tags: server, powerpc

In the Ubuntu documentation i have gone through PowerPC . Whats the matter with a Power PC and what are the good things if we compare with General PC .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerPCs dont have any special powers! :D

[PowerPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) is just the name for a different processor architecture (compared to x86).  PPCs were used most extensively by Apple for their Macs until 2006, when they switched to the usual Intel x86 ("General PC") architecture.

At this point, the PowerPC userbase consists mostly of people with the older Macs, and compared to any modern PC, a PowerPC is most certainly at a *disadvantage* when it comes to speed, graphics, etc.

> Note: This is not to imply that there is anything wrong with the PowerPC *architecture*; small embedded PPC processors are still used very successfully in peripherals like GPUs (eg PowerVR in the Intel CedarTrail platform), on RAID cards (eg 3ware 8xxx/9xxx), etc. Of course, that has nothing to do with Ubuntu :)

Comment: But you forgot to mention that IBM still uses them in high end computers, which are currently IBM POWER7 (eight cores with four threads each).  Next version are POWER8.  They are all PowerPC architecutres.  Some consoles are also using PowerPC, like Wii, Xbox 360 and PS/3.

Comment: @Anders Xbox is a modified x86 system, not PPC.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerPc is a type of CPU architecture developed by Apple, IBM and Motorola.
It has been used in Apples Mac computers from  1994 to 2006 now they have switched to Intel CPUs.

So if you don't have an old Mac these images aren't for you ;)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC